# returning an object retrieved from an NSMutableArray via objectAtIndex - autorelease necessary?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, autorelease

Scenario- I have a method that returns an object retrieved from an NSMutableArray similar to the following code which has been simplified (assume that "myArray" and "currentIndex" are iVars for the class wherein this method resides):

```
- (MyObject *)getFromArray
{
    return [myArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}
```

Should I be tacking on a call to autorelease like so?

```
- (MyObject *)getFromArray
{
    return [[myArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex] autorelease];
}
```

I know that autorelease is called on the object by the array as it returns said object, but my understanding is that the autoreleased object is only valid for the duration of the caller's scope, in this case, the method above.  So, would tacking on the autorelease (as shown above in the 2nd code snippet) be the correct way to make sure the object in question is valid for the caller of my method?  Just trying to make sure that my reasoning and understanding of how autorelease works is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I be tacking on a call to autorelease?

No! Always follow the simple memory management rules: if you don't own it (by `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `retain`), you must not (auto)release it.

> I know that autorelease is called on the object by the array as it returns said object

That assumption is wrong. The array just returns the object, it doesn't release it. (It might actually call `[[... retain] autorelease]` on the object but that's another matter.) The array will only release the object when you remove the object from the array or when the array itself gets deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  I was just going to post that I was having issues with my code because of my (bad) assumption about autorelease!

Comment: As a follow up, am I safe to just return the object retrieved from the array then?  Wouldn't it go out of scope and not be safe for the caller of getFromArray to use?

Comment: I thought I read something `autorelease`'ed objects are destroyed in the next run loop. So as long as it's not used in a next run loop it will exist further. You could add a `retain` statement on the returned object when you run the method (and then of course later on `release` it again). You could also use `- copyFromArray` and use `return [[myArray objectAtIndex:anIndex] retain];` and release it when you're done with it in further code.

Comment: Yes, you are safe just returning it. As lef2 said, the autorelease pool gets drained the next time your code returns control to the run loop. As long as you return just to the calling method you are fine.